# CSS/HTML responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm begginer. I want that on screens with 592px width or more to appear "1.png". And on the screens smaller than 592ox to appear another photo: "2.png".
What is wrong with the code? I can't get it right.

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .bg {
      background-image: url("1.png");
      height: 100%; 
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 592px) {
      body {
        display: none;
      }
    .bg2 {
      background-image: url("2.png");
      height: 100%; 
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: why `display:none;` has been set to `body`? that will disappear everything

Comment: Can you elobrate a bit on what you want to do? Perhaps a screenshot or something?

Comment: where is `bg2`?

Answer (score 0):

its only a css sintax error,

try this!

```css
<style>
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .bg {
      background-image: url("1.png");
      height: 100%; 
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    @media(max-width: 592px) {
    .bg {
      background-image: url("2.png");
    }
    }
</style>
```

explained: You only need to modify the url of the class .bg when screen is 592px.

let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I will simply write the answer. There a few other bad behaviors in the code too.

```
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bg {
  background-image: url("1.png");
  height: 100%; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 592px) {
 .bg {
   background-image: url("2.png");
 }
}
</style>


<div class="bg"></div>
```

- You can use window height like 100vh
- Do not put display:none for body tag

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine like this:

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .bg {
      height: 100%; 
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 592px) {
      .bg {
        background: url("1.png");
      }
    } 
    @media screen and (min-width: 592px) {
      .bg {
        background: url("2.png");
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
</body>
```

I think you were on the right path. But why did you apply "display: None" to the body? You have to declare what to do if it is smaller and what to do if it is bigger than your pixel threshold.